# not able to carry the form values through post method

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

There is a form where the user enters a number and according to the condition applied on the number, a list of addresses are displayed. I would like to store the data that is returned through AJAX. The code on the page that has a form:

index.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#phone").keyup(function() {  
            var number = $("#phone").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "t_fetchaddr.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'number='+number,
                cache: false,
                }).done(function(html) { 
                    $('#results').html(html);
                });
            });
        });

<script>

<form action="insert_temp.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="phoneno" id="phone" value=""  />
    <div id="results"></div>
    <button class="button btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

code on t_fetchaddr.php page

```
$val =  $_REQUEST['number']; 
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM user_address where number='".$val."' ";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) 
{ ?>
    <div class="span6" >
        <div class="span3">
            <? while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
            { ?>
                <input type="radio" name="old_address" value="<? echo $row2['address']; ?>" ><? echo $row2['address']; ?><br>
            <? } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<? } ?>
```

code on insert_temp.php page

```
$old_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['old_address']);
echo $old_address;
```

Everything is working fine until displaying of the address through number, but when I submit the form it is not going to the back end. I tried to `echo $old_address` but got nothing. 
other input values in index page inside the form are going to backend but `value that is being fetched from t_fetchaddr.php page is not getting carried`, Can anyone please tell where I went wrong

Comment: First mistake I see is `data: 'number='+number,` should be `data: {number:number},`

Comment: @BasvanStein That's not an issue; sending a string is fine - the object gets turned in to a querystring by jQuery anyway.

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if the request is actually being sent?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan the value is getting sent to the ajax, from there i am getting proper response, but after clicking on submit button i am not getting any response, but if i use any other input text that is placed directly on the main page, it get carried to  insert_temp.php page

Comment: Thank you @Rory McCrossan, I didn't know that, though I still find it ugly.

Comment: Just curious, you're sending data using POST and then defining it using REQUEST? `$val =  $_POST['number'];` isn't this better?

Comment: is your insert_temp.php page getting called?

Comment: @Gautam yes it is getting called, because my other values from index.php page inside the form is going but value from  <input type="radio" name="old_address" value="<? echo $row2['address']; ?>" ><? echo $row2['address']; ?> is not going

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#phone").keyup(function()
        {
            var number = $("#phone").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "t_fetchaddr.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {number :number}, //modified
                cache: false,
                success:function(html)
                {
                    $('#results').html(html);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>//Missing closing

<form action="insert_temp.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="phoneno" id="phone" value=""  />
    <div id="results"></div>
    <button class="button btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

and in php

```
$val =  $_POST['phoneno'];
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM user_address where number='".$val."' ";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0)
{ ?>
    <div class="span6" >
        <div class="span3">
            <? while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
            { ?>
                <input type="radio" name="old_address" value="<? echo $row2['address']; ?>" ><? echo $row2['address']; ?><br>
            <? } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<? } ?>
```

> Note:
>
> 1. Missing closing tag `</script>`
> 2. And this line changed `data: 'number='+number,`

Comment: tried but still not working, i need to carry old_address to backend

Comment: old_address  is the name of the input value that is being called through t_fetchaddr.php page, it's code <input type="radio" name="old_address" value="<? echo $row2['address']; ?>" ><? echo $row2['address']; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this and watch your console :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#phone").keyup(function() {  
        var number = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "t_fetchaddr.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {number:number},
            cache: false,
            success : function(html) { 
                $('#results').html(html);
            },
            error : function(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i didn't got any error in console everything worked fine, but still the value didn't got saved

Answer (score 0):

just try this code on fetchaddr.php
i have just removed the in between php tags.

```
<?
$val =  $_REQUEST['number']; 
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM user_address where number='".$val."' ";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) { 
    echo '<div class="span6" >
        <div class="span3">';
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
            { 
               echo '<input type="radio" name="old_address" value="'.$row2['address'].'" >'.$row2['address'].'<br>';
             } 
        echo '</div>
    </div>';
} ?>
```

hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: yes they are enabled, and besides other values are going to backend, the problem is just with  <input type="radio" name="old_address" value="<? echo $row2['address']; ?>" ><? echo $row2['address']; ?><br>